# How to make cells move up to close empty gaps in columns in Google Sheets?

Tags: sorting, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet, fill

I am working on a Google Sheets for my work and I am running into an issue where my code just takes the answer from one row and sticks it where it needs to go and leaves gaps.

The function is

```
RED
=IF(E7<=5, D7, “”)

YELLOW
=IF(OR(E7=6,E7=7),D7,””)

GREEN
=IF(E7>=8,D7,””)
```

With it changing the numbers as it goes down the columns

I have tried making a filter to remove blanks but it just removed a lot more than just blanks and makes it impossible to see the other two colors

[Here is a link to  demo page](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10LqnjDJiP4ka7NNWwcUqHj8mbO5bmAg3NU6cX-qjFG4/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: It would help if you could share a sample sheet with *realistic*-demo data and expected output(***manually entered***) so as for us to get a clear picture & workout a solution

Answer (score 0):

You may try:

*RED:*    `=filter(C2:C,D2:D<6)`

*YELLOW:* `=filter(C2:C,isbetween(D2:D,6,7))`

*GREEN:*  `=filter(C2:C,D2:D>7)`

[image]